# Symmetric matrix, value into c++ vector

Tags: c++, matrix

I am trying to solve the following problem. Let's say I have a symmetric matrix with size n. I want to take all the "important values", and store them into a vector. Let me give an example to explain it better.

Let's say I have the following matrix `A = [1, 2, 3 // 2, 5, 6 // 3, 6, 9]`. I want to define vector of size `n*(n+1)/2` such that:

```
V = [A(0,0), A(0,1), A(0,2), A(1,1), A(1,2), A(2,2) ]
```

I want to find a function that receives as input two integer `i` and `j`, and outputs the corresponding value of the matrix. The catch is that I do not want to access the matrix directly, instead I want to access the vector.

This is my reasoning so far. If I have an input with `j < i`, I just swap them since the matrix is symmetric. If I have that `i == 0`, the position in the array is just `j`. If that is not the case, I think I need to do something like this. (n is the dimension of the matrix, and position is the integer that I need when for the array.)

```
int position = 0;
for(int k = 0; k < i; k++){
   position = position + (n-k);
}
position = position + j % i;
```

However, this code fails. I think I'm close to the solution but I am missing something. Any help?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? You have a triangular matrix (since it is symmetric) and you only want to store half? That is a well-known problem and there are [existing matrix storage schemes](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node121.html) like [packed storage](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node123.html) for example.

Comment: Yes! Something like that, although I want to store the values row by row and not column by column. I'm going to study your links carefully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last `j % i` should be `j - i`.

---

In addition, the loop is essentially doing

```
position = n + (n - 1) + ... + (n - i + 1);
```

which can be simplified to

```
position = (n * 2 - i + 1) * i / 2;
```

So you can simply write

```
position = (n * 2 - i + 1) * i / 2 + j - i;
```

or

```
position = (n * 2 - i - 1) * i / 2 + j;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply this:

```
int myvector[matrix.size()];
int pos = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++){
     for(int j = 0; j < matrix.size(); j++){
        if(j > i) myvector[pos++] = matrix[i][j];
        else myvector[pos++] = matrix[j][i];
     }
 }
```